# php does not create a file when executed with cronjob

Tags: php, cron

I have a very simple php file, that creates a text document everytime it runs:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H-i-s', time());
$log_name = "Cronjob". $date;
if($fh = fopen($log_name,'w')){
    fwrite($fh, print_r($date));
    fclose($fh);
}
```

When I run the file using my browser a txt file is created on my server. When I run the file with a cronjob, it does NOT create a txt file.
When I go to private > cron.log on my server I see that the cronjob works fine and the result is printed into the cron.log.

Can someone tell me why? I need to write that file on the server :)

Comment: Could you use full path to `$log_name`? It was created but it could be somewhere. So, it is better to use full path to see if the file is created.

Comment: secondly check whether the directory you are using have full control? like read/write to the user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When executed in a cronjob, you need to provide the full path. The script does not executed in the directory it's located in, and therefor relative paths won't work.

```
$absolut_path = "whatever your absolutpath is"; // maybe something like /var/www/html/
$log_name = $absolut_path."Cronjob". $date;
```

Comment: does that mean that every path in my php files need to be with the absolute path? 
E.g. that function in another php file woun't work:

rename("/web/something.html", "/web/something-else.html");

Comment: ok, it works perfectly now: I use the following statement with dirname(__FILE__) to solve the problem:

$log_name = dirname(__FILE__)."/Cronjob". $date;

Comment: "/web/something.html" is a full path, so that should work.